# Summer 17 Web tab bug

Tags: lightning, summer-17, web-tab

Testing web tabs in a summer 17 sandbox and have come across an issue where it won't redirect to the page. [image]

The browsers dev console shows mostly warnings about deprecated methods being called, a load of console out and an error 
[image]

Does anyone know of any work arounds? Have I missed something or is this really an SF bug?